# Keywords from String

Tags: php, text, keyword

Does anyone know of an available PHP function that takes a piece of text, with say a few hundreds of words long and produces an array of keywords? Ie. the most important, frequently occuring unique terms?

Thanks
Philip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No such function exists (would be magical if it did) but to start something off, you could do the following:

1. [Split](http://www.php.net/explode) the text at the space,
   producing an array of words.
2. Remove [stop-words](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/idom/ir_resources/linguistic_utils/stop_words) and
   unnecessary punctuation and symbols (possibly using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - See [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace)).
3. Count the number of occurences of
   each word in the remaining array,
   and sort it in order of frequency
   (so the most frequently occuring word is at the first offset, i.e. `$words[0]`).
4. Use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/array_unique) to remove the
   duplicates, thus producing an array
   of unique keywords ordered by
   frequency of occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
$thestring = 'the most important, frequently occuring unique terms?';
$arrayofwords = explode(" ", $thestring);
echo print_r($arrayofwords);
```

Also you may replacement the comma "," for a blank, so you get clean keywords.

```
$thestring = 'the most important, frequently occuring unique terms?';
$cleaned_string = str_replace(",", "", "$thestring");
$arrayofwords = explode(" ", $cleaned_string);
echo print_r($arrayofwords);
```